# Pass section to handle click UISwitch in UITableViewCell - Swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiswitch, uitableviewsectionheader

I am working with `UISwitch` in `UITableViewCell` and I am passing the `row` like bellow:

```
.....
cell.swcSelectCourse.tag = indexPath.row
cell.swcSelectCourse.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleSWCSelectCourse(sender:)), for: .valueChanged)
.....

@objc func handleSWCSelectCourse(sender: UISwitch){
        let row = sender.tag
        let section = ?????
        let selectedIndex = IndexPath(row: row, section: ????)
}
```

But I need to `section` now, how can i pass section to `@objc func handleSWCSelectCourse` ?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50891714/unable-to-save-on-off-state-of-a-uitableviewcell/50894345#50894345. The index path is captured in the closure.

Comment: @ vadian. I need to have row and section for select values of my custom object.

Comment: As I said the index path  (section and row) is available in the closure. If cells can be inserted, deleted or moved pass also the cell in the closure to get the actual index path.

Comment: @  vadian. Your response is true for me. Thank's a lot. Insert your answer and then I accept it.

Comment: I marked the question as duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

Using the tag is really a hack, but as long as you're going for that, just use some of the tag bytes for the row and the others for the section. For example:

```swift
cell.swcSelectCourse.tag = indexPath.row + indexPath.section * 0x1000

/// and then later:
let row = tag % 0x1000
let section = tag / 0x1000
```

Of course, make sure you leave enough bytes for the expected number of rows and sections. And please, bounds check.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you should use delegate like this sample code

```
protocol SelectCourseCellDelegate: class {
     func didChangeSwitchValue(_ cell: Your Table View Cell, value: Bool)
}
```